# Android ViewModel class can't be initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

This is an InstantiationException for a ViewModel class defined in the MainActivity.  This is an app for counting timer which uses LiveData with ViewModel to display timer on the screen.

This is the error message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<ca.sheridancollege.fangyux.livedata_counterappausing.CounterViewModel> cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:322) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153) 
        at ca.sheridancollege.fangyux.livedata_counterappausing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This is my MainActivity

```
package ca.sheridancollege.fangyux.livedata_counterappausing

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val counterModel=ViewModelProvider(this).get(CounterViewModel::class.java)

        counterModel.startTimer()

        counterModel.getTimeLeft().observe(this, Observer {
            txt_counter.text = it.toString()
        })
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewModel class

```
package ca.sheridancollege.fangyux.livedata_counterappausing

import android.os.CountDownTimer
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

abstract class CounterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    lateinit var timer:CountDownTimer
    private val timeLeft=MutableLiveData<Int>()

    fun startTimer(){
        timer=object:CountDownTimer(10000,1000){
            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                timeLeft.value=(p0/1000).toInt()
            }

            override fun onFinish() {

            }
        }.start()
    }

    fun getTimeLeft():LiveData<Int>{
        return timeLeft
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with it?  Can anyone please help me with it?  Can anyone please help me with it?  Can anyone please help me with it?  Can anyone please help me with it?  Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Is your `CounterViewModel` meant to be an `abstract class`? You can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: Ohhh, it works.  Thank you so much, did not notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is declared as

```
abstract class CounterViewModel : ViewModel()
```

You cannot instantiate an abstract class, so remove the `abstract` keyword if you want to instantiate it.

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you so much, ianhanniballake